# Normative issues: Problems with function parameter rules

Tags: javascript, syntax, rules

```js
// the problem is not related to axios, just use it as an example

axios.get(url[, config])
```

`[, config]` means "config" is optional, but why is it optional. What specification is it based on? Or is it an unwritten rule ?

---

additional :

I wonder if there is a JavaScript synax document like [Value definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax%5D%20that%20defines%20the%20above%20%5B,%20config) to illustrate the above `[, config]`

Comment: Square brackets are a documentation convention for optional things that applies broadly, across multiple languages (and didn’t originate with JavaScript). The use of square brackets here is not related to the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 1):

It's based off of the defaults the writers of Axios has decided upon, in combination with any default values that you, the code-writer, may have implemented. See [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults):

> Config will be merged with an order of precedence. The order is library defaults found in lib/defaults.js, then defaults property of the instance, and finally config argument for the request. The latter will take precedence over the former.

Comment: sorry, the previous question was not clear, now update

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do my best to answer what I think your question is, but it's a little unclear to me still, so please leave a comment or update the question with more details if I don't quite answer what you were hoping for.

It appears you are trying to use the axios library to perform an HTTP(S) GET request, and you want to know why you do not have to specify the config every time.  From the [documentation on this page](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config), it appears that Axios has some defaults so that you do not have to specify all of the configuration for every HTTP(S) request you make.  If you want, you can override these defaults once for all function calls by following the examples on this [other page of the documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults).  If you want to see where they define their defaults, the [source code of the Axios library may have the info you're looking for](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/main/lib/defaults/index.js#L49).

Their documentation explains some of these default values which is a good practice for any library that has functions with what the authors consider "sensible" defaults, because in some cases this can be very subjective.  If you think their documentation is insufficient on the default values after looking through it and the source code above, you may consider reaching out to the developers directly to improve their docs or submit a pull request with an improvement to their documentation yourself.

I don't know that Axios' default values are a "specification" per se, but they do establish a convention for those that choose to use their library.  HTTP and HTTPS do have [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Resources_and_specifications) that might be good to be somewhat familiar with if you are creating web applications.  But typically libraries like Axios will provide some abstraction from most of these concepts for you.

If I were writing such a function for a library that takes an optional argument in javascript, I would likely be using the [default parameter syntax for functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), or if I were working with an old browser that did not support it, I would checking the argument's value and using some default if the parameter passed had the value `undefined`.

I hope some of this information helped.

Comment: sorry, the previous question was not clear, now update